# Initializing StringBuilder to use UTF-16 coder

Tags: java, stringbuilder, java-11

Consider the following code in Java 11:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("one");
sb.append("δύο");  // "two"
```

The first line creates a `StringBuilder` that uses the Latin1 coder (one byte per character). Then the second line causes the StringBuilder to realise that it needs to use the UTF16 coder instead, so it copies its current contents into a new array before appending the new UTF-16 characters.

The StringBuilder class has a constructor overload that takes an initial capacity argument, which is designed to avoid reallocation if you already know the required size of the string to be built. But if you start with an English string and then append a foreign string, this particular constructor overload is useless as it still reallocates the byte array.

Is there a way to create a StringBuilder instance that uses UTF16 right from the start?

Comment: alternative one way `sb.append(new String("δύο","UTF-16"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the Java 11 or Java 12 version of `StringBuilder` that would do this.

The real issue is how important to you is the performance increment that you might get from this.  *Profile your application* to find out if this unwanted reallocation contributes significantly to your application's *overall* performance.

If it is going to make a significant difference, you could implement your own version `StringBuilder` (extending the same interfaces for compatibility).

Alternatively, if you were prepare to wait, you could download the OpenJDK source code and develop / build / test an extension to `StringBuilder` ... and submit it as a patch for consideration.  (If you included benchmarks that demonstrated a clear performance benefit, that would help the chances of inclusion.)

Comment: The question is whether they actually want to include this in the JDK. Compact strings are an implementation detail and introducing a public method for them changes this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is no obvious one. If you wanted to influence the way StringBuffer initializes, my suggestion would be to create a utility 'initializer' that implements `CharSequence` and use the corresponding StringBuilder constructor. You can communicate any length and char content you wish with it, and StringBuilder internals should be smart enough to pick up on it.

Looking at the OpenJDK 11 implementation though, it seems hell-bent on starting with Latin1 no matter what. Some form of reallocation seems to always happen.

Comment: Thanks - interesting info.

Answer (score 1):

Having done a bit more research into this, I'm supplying another answer to my own question (Stack Overflow says it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.)

As [Slawomir says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56376654/8473028), StringBuilder gets initialized with Latin1 no matter what. So suppose you primarily write in a language such as Russian, Chinese, Hindi or Greek. You want to build a string whose maximum size you already know, so you use the initial capacity argument:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4096);
sb.append("Здравствуйте!");  // Should easily fit in 4 kilobytes, right?
```

Yet the above call to `append` throws away the 4KB buffer that you previously initialized and allocates a new buffer. You constructed the StringBuilder with an initial capacity in order to avoid reallocating a buffer, but the StringBuilder reallocated it anyway. And it reallocated it even though it was already big enough!

**A workaround is to run java using the JVM option `-XX:-CompactStrings`.**

If you consistently use one of these languages, then your Strings will use UTF-16 anyway, so turning off string compaction at startup will reduce the overhead of checking every string you supply to see if it can be stored using Latin1 encoding.

See also [Heinz Kabutz's talk at jPrime Bulgaria, 29 May 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OL4Ye2r7ohY) where he causes StringBuilder to run out of memory due to this "feature".